# Create a top Bond (ALB) on 2 lower Bond (LACP)

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

Is it possible to create a BOND over a BOND? or this will cause some networking issue?

Why do I need this setup?
I have 2 switch that support LACP but not distributed LACP!
My Server has 4 ethernet and I was thinking about bond with LACP 2 nic per switch and get the best performance from every single switch.

Teaming up the 2 LACP bond with an ALB bond in order to be connected in both the 2 switches.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot bond bonds, what you actually want is to configure two LACP Aggregators.

See my answer here at Unix Stackexchange:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82569/bonds-vs-aggregators